# Nginx Laravel some Button don't work anymore over night, change url but no results

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5

I have hostet an Laravel Website with Nginx on Ubuntu.
Yesterday all works fine and now some Button dont work anymore!

For example the "Message open" Button and the "next page" or "page number".

If i want click on an page number or next page i see the link in browser and also then i the url bar from browser after clicking but always the same page:((

I have install some NGINX and PHP security for 2 Days. Harden PHP and NGINX. Maybe thats the problem that someone in nginx or php settings block it.

Script works fine always without problems and i dont know whats the problem, it must be nginx!

Comment: Did you check the error log server and client side? It could be a myriad of issues, it's impossible for one to tell without more detail

Comment: Yes no laravel errors and no nginx errors

Comment: All other works but not the message open button and next page

Comment: if i install an new test laravel project it loads also no logo and captcha and say localhost:5678/img/test.jpg contains an error

Comment: By client side, I meant in the Javascript console

Comment: Script is without any javascript